# Solution of Inverse parametric implicit functions

Tags: differential-equations

Using [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) I solved for functions $G={x,y,u,v}$ that are functions of $t$

\begin{eqnarray} 
y'(t) &=& f(x) \\ 
x'(t) &=& g(y) \\
u'(t) &=& p(x,y)\\ 
v'(t) &=& q(x,y) 
\end{eqnarray}

with boundary conditions in a given domain.

How can I find, by means of an ODE or by *Mathematica* numerical procedure, $t$ as function of $G$s? I do not want to plot results available because I wish to be able to compute and plot $t$ at uniform increments of each of the four $G$s.

@ bbgodfrey Thank you. Somehow, I got stuck with elementary things.There are two simple questions below. Writing here,it being too big in comments area.

```
Clear[x,y,tx,ty]
ss=NDSolve[{x'[t]==y[t],y'[t]==-x[t],x[0]==1,y[0]==0},{x,y},{t,0,Pi}]//Flatten;
(* How to plot x,y = cos, -sin before the function inversion?  *)
{tx=InverseFunction[x/.ss],ty=InverseFunction[y/.ss]};
Plot[tx[x],{x,-1,1},AspectRatio->1,AxesLabel->{x,t}]
Plot[ty[y],{y,-Pi,Pi},AspectRatio->1,AxesLabel->{y,t}]
(*  I am unable to recognize  that ty is the -arcsin function, but tx looks ok  *)
```

Comment: You should provide a concrete example and the code you have already tried yourself.

Comment: At the outset found it formidable, posted it as I found it normally not done at least afaik. However, shall soon post a representative example soon.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for such a fine edit.

Answer (score 2):

Solving the four equations will yield expressions for `x`, `y`, `u` and `v`.  Inverting any one of them will yield `t` as a function of the corresponding G.  In fact, it is more straightforward to solve only the first two equations and invert one of the solutions.  A simple example that can be solved analytically is

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t] // Flatten
(* {x[t] -> Cos[t], y[t] -> -Sin[t]} *)
Solve[# /. Rule -> Equal /. {x[t] -> x, y[t] -> y}, t] & /@ %
(* {{{t -> ConditionalExpression[-ArcCos[x] + 2 π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
     {t -> ConditionalExpression[ArcCos[x] + 2 π C[1],  C[1] ∈ Integers]}}, 
    {{t -> ConditionalExpression[-ArcSin[y] + 2 π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
     {t -> ConditionalExpression[π + ArcSin[y] + 2 π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}}} *)
```

**Numerical Computation**

In the event that numerical evaluation is needed, the following procedure works.

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}] 
    // Flatten;
{tx = InverseFunction[x /. s], ty = InverseFunction[y /. s]};
```

and the functions `tx` and `ty` can be plotted like any other functions.  For instance,

```
Plot[tx[x], {x, Cos[1], 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x, t}]
```

[image]

gives the same curve as

```
Plot[ArcCos[x], {x, Cos[1], 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x, t}]
```

as it should.